# How could I resolve the pytorch size mismatch error?

Tags: pytorch

I'm working on an Atari reinforcement learning project using PyTorch and encountered a size mismatch error. The error message is as follows:

> size mismatch for 7.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([512, 3136]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([512, 409600]).

It appears that my code generates a shape of 409600, but it should be 3136. Below is the relevant portion of my source code:

```
self.q_network = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=n_channels * self.config["hyper_params"]["state_history"], out_channels=32, kernel_size=8, stride=4, padding=((4-1)*img_height-4+8)//2),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=((2-1)*img_height-2+4)//2),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=((1-1)*img_height-1+3)//2),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear(64 * img_height * img_width, 512),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=num_actions)
)
```

What modifications should I make to resolve this size mismatch issue?

Comment: looks like `64 * img_height * img_width` is 409600 . maybe try hardcoding `3136` over there and see if it works ?

Comment: if i change with 3136 there, it returns RuntimeError: linear(): input and weight.T shapes cannot be multiplied (1x409600 and 3136x512)"